# where can i get good example to write client-server application in websocket?

Tags: java, websocket

where can i get good example to write client-server application as I am new to **WebSocket**. I don't know where can i find implementation in JAVA. I want to build client server application

Answer (score 0):

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/), it has demos page there.

Answer (score 0):

Kaazing has a great [peer-to-peer WebSocket tutorial](http://tutorial.kaazing.com) using Java Message Service (JMS). It walks through some simple code step-by-step, comes with a screencast and is fully integrated with JSFiddle code snippets.

[image: WebSocket Tutorial in JSFiddle]